# Ajax with XML Autocomplete URL return issue

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xml, autocomplete

This is where I got my code from:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp

```
if ($hint=="") {
  $hint="<a href='" . 
  $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . 
  "' target='_blank'>" . 
  $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>";
} else {
  $hint=$hint . "<br /><a href='" . 
  $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . 
  "' target='_blank'>" . 
  $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>";
}
```

Let's say my website URL is "www.example.com" when I click the result that shown, I got into the URL that is "https://www.example.com/www.example.com/something.html"

How could I make it right?

Comment: By adding the protocol in front, so that this becomes an actual absolute URL, and not a relative one.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the HTTP Protocol to avoid this issue.

```
if ($hint=="") {
   $hint="<a href='https://" . $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "' target='_blank'>" . 
   $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>";
} else {
    $hint=$hint . "<br /><a href='https://" . $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "' target='_blank'>" . 
    $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>";
}
```

You can make this dynamic as well rather than hardcoding to `https://`